# Closing an open file automatically on quit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make it so that python automatically closes open files when the player attempts to quit?

This is what I have so far:

```
hai = open('hai.txt','a')
quit = 0
while quit == 0:
    hai.write('SPAM')
hai.close()
```

Comment: In most cases, even without using the 'with' statement, python will take of that for you. http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
with open("file.txt","a") as f:
    #Do things with f
```